# tikz - relative coordinates of a second position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a kind of sequence diagram but I don't want to calculate every position.

I want to use relative coordinates. With the command `coodinate` I set the first coordinate (0.25,14.25) as `a`, but I want to select a second coordinate (0.25,14.75).

Is there a way to do this?

```
%Actor
\draw[dashed] (0.25,15) -- (0.25,0)  node[above=15] {User};
\draw[dashed] (6,15) -- (6,0)  node[above=15] {HMI};
\draw[dashed] (12,15) -- (12,0) node[above=15] {Server1};
\draw[dashed] (18,15) -- (18,0) node[above=15] {Server2};
%
%Blocks
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw[line width=5pt] (0.25,14.25) -- (0.25,14.75)  node[midway, right] {Test} coordinate (a);
\end{scriptsize}
%
%Arrows
\begin{scope}[>=latex]
\draw[->,black] (a) -- (6,14);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please can you add a complete MWE? What are packages that you use?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using the `calc` library (See Section 13.5 Coordinate Calculations of the pgf manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (b) at (0,-2);
  \node[draw=red] at (a) {a};
  \node[draw=red] at (b) {b};
  \draw[help lines] (-1,-3) grid (3,3);
  \draw ($ (a) + (0,1) $) -- ($ (b) + (0,1) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have it a bit confused. Your `coordinate (a)` (which is an empty node) is really `(0.25,14.75)`, at the end of the path.

To have a  "marker" for the start and end of the path you can do:

```
    %Blocks
    \begin{scriptsize}
        \draw[line width=5pt] (0.25,14.25) coordinate(b) -- 
             (0.25,14.75)  node[midway, right] {Test} coordinate (a);
    \end{scriptsize}
    %
    %Arrows
    \begin{scope}[>=latex]
        \draw[->,black] (a) -- ++(1,0) node {a};
        \draw[->,black] (b) -- ++(1,0) node {b};
    \end{scope}
```

and you'll have (partial graph):

[image: Partial shot of the result]

In general, you can have node on whichever part of the path, with the `pos` key; if you add

```
        \draw[line width=5pt] (0.25,14.25) coordinate(b) -- 
           (0.25,14.75)  node[midway, right] {Test} 
           coordinate (a)  coordinate[pos=0.5](c);
```

and

```
       \draw[->,black] (c) -- ++(2,0) node {c};
```

you have:

[image: Adding a point in the middle]

Notice also that the `midway` keys is really another way of saying `pos=0.5`.

Answer (score 2):

**First Answer:** Use the package `tikz-uml`, it offers also support for sequence diagrams. See [perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/); the sequence diagrams are documented [here](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/var/files/html/web-tikz-uml-userguidech5.html#x7-740005).

**Second Answer:** If you want to do it yourself using the tikz commands directly, I suggest to

- use commands for constants, like `\xUser` and `\xHmi` for the horizontal positions of the time lines
- use nodes for actors and actions and name them
- define styles for the parameters of the nodes.

Then it will be easy to adjust and extend the diagram. Here is an example how you can do it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset
  {actor/.style={font=\ttfamily},
   action/.style 2 args= % first arg is length in mm, second arg is label
     {minimum width=3mm,minimum height=#1mm,inner sep=0pt,
      draw,fill=blue!30,anchor=north,label={right:\scriptsize#2}
     },
   message/.style={-stealth,font=\scriptsize\bfseries},
   timeline/.style={dashed}
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm,y=1mm]
  % horizontal position of actors (in mm)
  \newcommand\xUser{0}
  \newcommand\xHmi{20}
  \newcommand\xSa {40}
  \newcommand\xSb {60}
  % actors
  \node[actor] (user-0) at (\xUser,0) {User}; 
  \node[actor] (hmi-0)  at (\xHmi ,0) {HMI};
  \node[actor] (s1-0)   at (\xSa  ,0) {Server1};
  \node[actor] (s2-0)   at (\xSb  ,0) {Server2};
  % time lines
  \newcommand\yTimeMax{-65}
  \draw[timeline] (user-0) -- +(0,\yTimeMax); % example for relative positioning
  \draw[timeline] (hmi-0)  -- +(0,\yTimeMax);
  \draw[timeline] (s1-0)   -- +(0,\yTimeMax);
  \draw[timeline] (s2-0)   -- +(0,\yTimeMax);
  % actions (first arg is length in mm, second arg is label)
  \node[action={10}{$A_1$}] (user-1) at (\xUser,-10) {};
  \node[action={ 5}{$A_2$}] (hmi-1)  at (\xHmi ,-20) {};
  \node[action={15}{$A_3$}] (s1-1)   at (\xSa  ,-25) {};
  \node[action={10}{$A_4$}] (user-2) at (\xUser,-50) {};
  % messages
  \draw[message] (user-1.south east) -- node[above]{a} (hmi-1.north west);
  \draw[message] (hmi-1.south east)  -- node[above]{b} (s1-1.north west);
  \draw[message] (s1-1.south west)   -- node[above]{c} (user-2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```